# Python os.system('start path_to_batch_file') won't show up new cmd window when invoked via taskmanager

Tags: python, python-2.7, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2008-r2

**Edit:**
it worked when i choose the "Run only when user is logged on" option under the security option of the task scheduler.so it looks like it has something to do with "Run whether user is logged in or not" option

---

The python script calls an external batch file using `os.system('start path_to_batch_file')`

everything works when calling the script directly from the command line.

when i execute it via the task scheduler, it won't show up the new cmd window.but, i can see the new **cmd.exe** process from the task manager.

inside the bat file there is a call to the **firefox.exe**. it's same for the Firefox as well.i can see it from the task manager but not the Firefox window.

Task scheduler execute the script as `C:\Python27\python.exe script.py`.i've also tried `cmd /c script.py`

i've also tried `os.system('start')` (without any arguments and it's still the same)

**Python: 2.7**

**OS: Windows Server 2008 R2**

Any help would be appreciated.